# How can I show files as a picture on my website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-view-controller

I have a list, where I want to show a picture. And I use "**MVC/cshtml**" with "**.Net Core**"
Pictures never shown, while the path I give is correct. The other pictures are png-files with a transparent background.

This is what I get:

[image]

This is the location of the files:

[image]

What's the reason I can't show the pictures?

This is the declaration. The name of the file is correct too. I can find them in the map.

```
@{
   string sImageFile = "~/images/artiesten/" + item.ArtiestnaamVolledig + ".jpg";
}
```

And this are commands for showing the pictures.

```
            @if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sImageFile))
            {
                sImageFile = "~/images/artiesten/Gitaar.png";
            }
            <td class="notering_images">
                <img src="@sImageFile" alt="-" height="50" width="50" />
            </td>
```

Comment: I'm noticing that your default image is a .png, while you're filling in .jpg on sImageFile. Are those the correct extensions for your files?

Comment: Yes I see it. It's code from 8 years ago. And I'm developing my website from scratch in a whole environment. But the files has those extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a test, when use the img tag

```
<img src="~/images/artiesten/Gitaar.png" alt="-" height="50" width="50" />
```

the image can be rendered correctly and the generated html code is like below:

```
<img src="/images/artiesten/Gitaar.png" alt="-" height="50" width="50">
```

So, just remove the `~`

```
sImageFile = "/images/artiesten/Gitaar.png";
```

Comment: Thank you... Only this part doesn't work.                 @{
                    string tempFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(ViewBag.WebRootPath, sImageFile);//.Replace("/", "\\"));
                    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(tempFile))
                    {
                        sImageFile = "/images/artiesten/Gitaar.png";
                    }
                }

Comment: Do you have also a correct solution of that part File.Exists? You have given the correct answer of my question. It works.